# "I" vs. "me" question

Tags: grammar, american-english

**I was born in United States but at a young age my parents decided to take me and my siblings to Turkey.**

It looks right to me, but my English teacher always (and I mean always) points out mistakes with I/me.

I remove the "and my siblings" and it becomes: **my parents decided to take me to Turkey.**

That sounds about right to me, but English isn't my first language. Can you give me a hand?

Comment: Your analysis is quite right. It is *me and my siblings* in your sentence, and that's correct.

Comment: Thanks! Err, should I delete the thread since there is no answer?

Comment: No: someone will come along with a real answer, or suggest a duplicate (I'm sure such a question will have been asked before). You might want to alter the title to refer to what the question is **about**, though: perhaps 'Is "take me and my siblings" correct?'

Comment: Given that English isn't your first language, you might want to check out [ell.se]. You might find some of your future questions to be more suitable for that site. See [ELL vs ELU](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3722) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I hope the thread title is acceptable.

Uh, no.  A title should distinguish a post from all other posts.  Pretty much any e.se post could be named "Check this for me".

> I was born in United States but at a young age my parents decided to take me and my siblings to Turkey.

Your parents were young when they decided to take you to Turkey?

No.  *You* were the young one.  (Avoid "at a young age".  Besides being verbose, it is idiomatically questionable: the age is "early"; the person is young.)

Also, the name of the US (like the UK, the Netherlands, and for some reason, the Ukraine) takes the definite article.

So:

> I was born in the United States, but when I was still young, my parents took me and my siblings to Turkey.

It isn't enough they decide to take you to Turkey; they had to actually do it.

Comment: You have managed to address everything except what was actually asked about! :-)

Comment: Wow I didn't even realize that about my parents being young. Thanks for that!

Comment: @Malvolio. To say that *they decided to take* their offspring to Turkey is normal and natural.

Comment: @tunny - I think it would be fine in casual speech, but in formal writing, the reader might expect something to be made of the implied distinction: "My parents decided to take me and my siblings to Turkey *but civil unrest prevented them from doing so*."

Comment: @Davud -- your error, a [dangling modifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_modifier), is a common one, even among native English speakers.  As Groucho Marx famously said, "One morning I shot an elephant in my pajamas. How he got into my pajamas I'll never know."

Comment: @Malvolio. In formal writing, more context would make it clear whether they actually went or not. I think that if we use "X decided to ...", the normal assumption is that the action decided on happened, unless the speaker/writer makes it clear that it did not. I was about to go to bed a few minutes ago, but **I decided to wait up** to see if you would reply.

Comment: @Malvolio: There is an [implicature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicature) that an action follows the decision, but it can be cancelled as with all implicatures (e.g. using your "but civil unrest..."). The meaning should be available in any text, formal or otherwise, except legal (where you want to leave no leeway for possible alternate interpretations, no matter how improbable).

Comment: @Amadan -- I just don't hear the implicature there.  I was genuinely expecting an explanation of why they either didn't go to Turkey or didn't go until the narrator was no longer young.